What's the right setting to prefix the request in chrome extension?
For years, I usually struggled at proxy and redirect thing, and it comes when I trying to make a chrome extension.
Now I'm making a manifest v3 extension with "chrome.declarativeNetRequest",
instead of using "chrome.webRequest" which will no longer there soon.
And I'll try to make a Dynamic rediect with URL path later
But no luck even static rule, it proxy all the websites, not only the domain I declared in code.
Result should be
GET https://www.dmm.com/things 
into
GET https://kcwiki.github.io/cache/things
in the end.  But what's my misunderstanding ?
here's the code
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Dynamic Declarative Redirect Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "declarativeNetRequest"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "file:///*",
        "*://*.dmm.com/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": [
                "*/*"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "*://www.dmm.com/*",
                "*://osapi.dmm.com/*",
                "*://kcwiki.github.io/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

const initialRules = [
    {
        id: 1,
        priority: 1,
        action: {
            type: 'redirect',
            redirect: {
                url: 'https://kcwiki.github.io/cache'
            }
        },
        condition: {
            urlFilter: '*://test.example.com/*',
            resourceTypes: ["main_frame"]
        }
    }
];
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(async () => {
    // Get arrays containing new and old rules
    const oldRules = await chrome.declarativeNetRequest.getDynamicRules();
    const oldRuleIds = oldRules.map(rule => rule.id);

    await chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
        removeRuleIds: oldRuleIds
    }, async () => {
        await chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
            addRules: initialRules
        }, () => {
            console.log("Rule Set")
        });
    });
})

The Answer code sample and mark up my fault.


When redirecting, your "host_permissions" must include both the source and the target site.
To change parts of a URL use regexFilter + regexSubstitution.
To avoid an installation warning "This extension can block any URL" use "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess" instead of "declarativeNetRequest" in "permissions"

// manifest.json
  "permissions": ["declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess"],
  "host_permissions": ["file:///*", "*://*.dmm.com/", "https://kcwiki.github.io/"],

// background.js
const initialRules = [{
  id: 1,
  action: {
    type: 'redirect',
    redirect: {
      regexSubstitution: 'https://kcwiki.github.io/cache/\\1',
    },
  },
  condition: {
    requestDomains: ['www.dmm.com'],
    regexFilter: '^https?://www\\.dmm\\.com/(.*)',
    resourceTypes: ['main_frame'],
  },
}];


you literally a hero, that's really clear, but why my extension still trying to redirect all the other URL ?
includeing kcwiki.github.io itself ?

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/api-samples/declarativeNetRequest/url-redirect
Even I try official sample still getting blank page

unfortunately, that's all code already, did yours work fine ?

Your code in the question can redirect only test.example.com, the code in the answer can only redirect www.dmm.com. The situation you describe is physically impossible and the only explanation is that you have another rule or another extension or it's a critical bug in the browser. Try disabling all extensions, then remove your test extension, delete _metadata folder inside, install the test extension again.

I'll keep trying, thank you
